# C# Winforms, Distinct double click from expanding the tree node in TreeView

Tags: c#, winforms, treeview, events, double-click

I need to distinct the action in `BeforeExpand` event of `TreeView`. The problem is that the `DoubleClick` event is fired after the `BeforeExpand` event.

When a user double clicks the tree node the `DoubleClick` event is fired - which is ok, but the node is expanded/collapsed. I'd like to limit that the user needs to click `+` to expand the node and block the expand/collapse on double click - is this even possible? The `TreeViewCancelEventArgs` isn't much of a help since there is no information on how the node is expanded...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C# System.Windows.Forms.TreeView: Stop auto expand/collapse on double-click (and execute another handler)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1307891/c-sharp-system-windows-forms-treeview-stop-auto-expand-collapse-on-double-click)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Stop auto expand/collapse on double-click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1307891/solved-c-system-windows-forms-treeview-stop-auto-expand-collapse-on-double-cli)